# Realm db copy to stream

Tags: .net, realm

Now that the Realm folks have added the in memory database (myget), is it possible to back that database up to a stream so it can be stored somewhere?  The only method I see is `WriteCopy` which can create a copy but as far as I know it would be on the file system.

I'm trying to avoid touching the file system and being able to back up the database to potentially migrate dynamically to another server (the bytes would be stored in a db or in the cloud somewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API currently that will allow you to do that, and additionally, there is no API that would allow you to construct a database from a stream (in case you need to restore it). If you open a Github issue, the team will take a look and assess the feasibility of exposing it.

Comment: This is the main reason I can't use SQLite.  I'll consider opening a github issue.